# design a data structure and algorithm to store key-value in a malloced memory

Tags: database, algorithm, data-structures

I am writing a config library, the config is key value set. e.g. ip=192.168.10.1

the config is stored in a config file, and loaded into a shared memory (shmctl/shmget).

the library provide apis for fast load, query, insert, delete, save。

the config is cached to shared memory, so I need design how to store key-value set into a linear memory. and how to insert/query/delete to/from memory.

my bad implmentation is store key value one by one, but that is very inefficient for any operation.

Comment: And you are not allowed to use a hashmap?

Comment: @Surt allowed，but how to store the hash map to a single continous memory

Comment: see my answer on open addressing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is [open addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing). Basically what this means is that you store the data by getting a hash value modulus the hashmap length and putting them in that address. If you got a collision you can chose from different policies to solve it.

An example is linear probing which just means that you find the first open spot after the wished position. Regardless of what policy you chose you have to make changes to how you find, delete, resize. Getting the best is difficult as it depends on your usage behaviour.

If you are lucky you can find a [perfect hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) which means you get no collisions, but that is a science in itself.

Alternatively you can just use your languages hashmap.